How to transform flat array to a list of hierarchical trees based on a field with a list of enums denoting the level
I'm trying to transform a flat list of account balances to a list of hierarchical account trees based on a list of unique codes. I'm struggling with how to solve this as I can't see what steps to take.
If you think of an excel sheet then the account balance would be a row and the codes field denotes the columns for how many levels the row has been broken down into. This effectively means that the the first codes[0] is the first level and codes[1] would be the next so on and so forth. By transforming the account balances to an account tree I want to sum the amountOut correctly for each level (codeType and code) and then add it as an account tree in the subAccounts array.
Below I've added all the types used as well as provided an example of the input and output.
interface AccountBalance {
    id: string
    codes: Code[]
    amountOut: number
}

type Code = {
    id: string
    codeType: CodeTypes
    code: string
    description: string
}

enum CodeTypes {
    account = "account",
    responsible = "responsible",
    project = "project",
    object = "object",
    counterPart = "counterPart",
    free = "free",
}

type AccountTree = {
    id: string
    name: string
    code: string
    amountOut: number
    subAccounts: AccountTree[]
}

Input example:
const accountBalances: AccountBalance[] = [
            {
                id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2d9b",
                codes: [
                    {
                        id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2c2d",
                        codeType: codeTypeEnum.account,
                        code: "1250",
                        description: "Column A",
                    },
                    {
                        id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2bd5",
                        codeType: codeTypeEnum.responsible,
                        code: "17",
                        description: "Column B",
                    },
                    {
                        id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2bf7",
                        codeType: codeTypeEnum.counterPart,
                        code: "20",
                        description: "Column C",
                    },
                ],
                amountOut: 24510549,
            },
            {
                id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2d9c",
                codes: [
                    {
                        id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2c2d",
                        codeType: codeTypeEnum.account,
                        code: "1250",
                        description: "Column A",
                    },
                    {
                        id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2bee",
                        codeType: codeTypeEnum.responsible,
                        code: "40",
                        description: "Column B",
                    },
                    {
                        id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2c08",
                        codeType: codeTypeEnum.counterPart,
                        code: "S3",
                        description: "Column C",
                    },
                ],
                amountOut: 0,
            },
            {
                id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2d9d",
                codes: [
                    {
                        id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2c2d",
                        codeType: codeTypeEnum.account,
                        code: "1250",
                        description: "Column A",
                    },
                    {
                        id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2bdb",
                        codeType: codeTypeEnum.responsible,
                        code: "80",
                        description: "Column B",
                    },
                    {
                        id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2bdc",
                        codeType: codeTypeEnum.counterPart,
                        code: "52",
                        description: "Column C",
                    },
                ],
                amountOut: 6381398,
            },
        ]

Output I want, example:
const expected: AccountTree = {
            id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2c2d",
            name: "Column A",
            code: "1250",
            amountOut: 30891947,
            subAccounts: [
                {
                    id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2bd5",
                    name: "Column B",
                    code: "17",
                    amountOut: 24510549,
                    subAccounts: [
                        {
                            id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2bf7",
                            name: "Column C",
                            code: "20",
                            amountOut: 24510549,
                            subAccounts: [],
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2bee",
                    name: "Column B",
                    code: "40",
                    amountOut: 0,
                    subAccounts: [
                        {
                            id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2c08",
                            name: "Column C",
                            code: "S3",
                            amountOut: 0,
                            subAccounts: [],
                        },
                    ],

                },
                {
                    id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2bdb",
                    name: "Column B",
                    code: "80",
                    amountOut: 6381398,
                    subAccounts: [
                        {
                            id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2bdc",
                            name: "Column C",
                            code: "52",
                            amountOut: 6381398,
                            subAccounts: [],
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        }

What I've gotten so far is this
const uniqueCodeTypes = [
        ...new Set(
            accountBalances.reduce<CodeTypes[]>(
                (acc, balance) => [
                    ...acc,
                    ...balance.codes.flatMap((code) => code.codeType),
                ],
                [],
            ),
        ),
    ]

    const uniqueCodesForCodeType = uniqueCodeTypes.map((codeType) => {
        const uniqueCodesForCodeType = [
            ...new Map(
                accountBalances.reduce<Code[]>((acc, balance) => {
                    const code = balance.codes.find(
                        (code) => code.codeType === codeType,
                    )
                    return code ? [...acc, code] : acc
                }, []).map((code) => [code.code, code])
            ).values(),
        ]
        return uniqueCodesForCodeType
    })

But I'm unsure of how to proceed after this.

In the expected output, how would you arrive at amountOut: 30891947?

@trincot Since 1250 is the top of the tree, that would mean it's the total sum of the next level i.e 17 + 40 + 80. 17 has 24510549, 40 has 0 and 80 has 6381398. In total that would be 30891947.

In plain Javascript, you could search for id at the same level and add object if not exists.


const
    codeTypeEnum = { account: "account", responsible: "responsible", project: "project", object: "object", counterPart: "counterPart", free: "free"},
    accountBalances = [{ id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2d9b", codes: [{ id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2c2d", codeType: codeTypeEnum.account, code: "1250", description: "Column A" }, { id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2bd5", codeType: codeTypeEnum.responsible, code: "17", description: "Column B" }, { id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2bf7", codeType: codeTypeEnum.counterPart, code: "20", description: "Column C" }], amountOut: 24510549 }, { id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2d9c", codes: [{ id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2c2d", codeType: codeTypeEnum.account, code: "1250", description: "Column A" }, { id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2bee", codeType: codeTypeEnum.responsible, code: "40", description: "Column B" }, { id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2c08", codeType: codeTypeEnum.counterPart, code: "S3", description: "Column C" }], amountOut: 0 }, { id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2d9d", codes: [{ id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2c2d", codeType: codeTypeEnum.account, code: "1250", description: "Column A" }, { id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2bdb", codeType: codeTypeEnum.responsible, code: "80", description: "Column B" }, { id: "671769fbd36fcd6c2c7f2bdc", codeType: codeTypeEnum.counterPart, code: "52", description: "Column C" }], amountOut: 6381398 }],
    result = accountBalances.reduce((r, { amountOut, codes }) => {
        codes.reduce((level, o) => {
            let target = level.find(({ id, codeType }) => id === o.id && codeType === o.codeType);
            if (!target) {
                target = { ...o, amountOut: 0, subAccounts: [] };
                level.push(target);
            }
            target.amountOut += amountOut;
            return target.subAccounts;
        }, r);

        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }




This seems to almost work, though it doesn't seem to take into account the cases where the code is different for the same code type. I'm looking to return a list of all the parents with their respective tree. This seems to only handle one where the Column A  code would be the same for all the account balances, but that won't be the case (codeType will be the same, but not code).

you could search for same lcodeType. please see edit.

I believe I originally made an error when I tested this, it seems to work perfectly. Thank you very much!
